# What does it mean that "commits will be rebased" when changing a commit's tag name?

Tags: git, git-tag, gitkraken

So I'm using gitkraken. I've previously tagged a commit with the tag 'TPE1'. Since then I've made some changes and now I want to delete that tag (or rename it) and make my last commit the one with the tag 'TPE1'.

When trying to rename the old tag GitKraken warns me:

```
Rewording this commit message will cause 5 commits to be rebased.
```

What does this mean? Could I lose any changes from those 5 commits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means you've somehow selected the commit the tag points to instead of the tag itself, and gitKraken believes you want to change its commit message. But since you can't change a commit's message without modifying its hash, it needs to be rebased as a consequence, with all its following children up to the tip.

Since that's *not* what you want to do, cancel at the warning step.

Moving a tag should not cause you to rebase anything.

---

If you don't find it in GitKraken interface, maybe consider just doing it from the command line, with

```
# for a lightweight (unannotated) tag
git tag -f <tagName> <commitHash>

# ...or for a proper (annotated) tag
git tag -f -m "<tagMessage>" <tagName>
```

(or just omit the `<commitHash>` part if your `HEAD` points at the commit you want to tag (the most recent you refered to).

Comment: Thank you. I was indeed selecting the wrong options. I made right click on the tatg and deleted it locally and on the origin. Then created the tag again.